# API authentication using rCURL

Tags: r, api, authentication, rcurl

I am super new to R, I tried to connect to Rosette API via R and I got curl script below. How do I internet this to R? I got my personal API key.

```
curl "https://api.rosette.com/rest/v1/ping" -H 'X-RosetteAPI-Key: [your_api-key]'
```

Thanks
Peddie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `curlconverter` package was tailor-made for this.

You can take your `cURL` command line and either copy it to the clipboard or pass it in directly. If you copy it to the clipboard then you call `straighten()` with no parameters:

```
library(curlconverter)

flat <- straighten()
```

otherwise, you can pass it in as a string:

```
flat <- straighten("curl 'https://api.rosette.com/rest/v1/ping' -H 'X-RosetteAPI-Key: [your_api-key]'")
```

That makes a list of all the URL parts which you can then pass into `make_req()`:

```
req <- make_req(flat)[[1]]
```

`make_req()` turns that list into a fully functional `httr` call. It's vectorized, which is why it returns a list of one or more functions vs just a function.

If you just pass in just one object, then it also copies the generated function source to the clipboard, which you can paste back into your IDE. This one generates:

```
httr::VERB(verb = "GET", url = "https://api.rosette.com/rest/v1/ping", 
    httr::add_headers(`X-RosetteAPI-Key` = "[your_api-key]"))
```

NOTE that you could also see that source by just entering `req` (no parens) at the R console.

I usually examine the output and make it a bit more compact:

```
GET(url = "https://api.rosette.com/rest/v1/ping", 
    add_headers(`X-RosetteAPI-Key` = "[your_api-key]"))
```

It imports/exports `%>%` so it's possible to — after copying a `cURL` command-line to the clipboard — do:

```
straighten() %>% make_req() -> req
```

A fairy common subset of `cURL` command line options are supported. If one is missing that you need, just [file an issue](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter/issues) with an example. Speaking of examples, there are [many more usage examples](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter) at the gh repo.

Comment: Very useful tips! Thank you. For more information, visit https://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter and https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/02/craft-httr-calls-cleverly-with-curlconverter/ .